# Creating correct D3D11 library file for GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, directx-11

What is the correct way to convert files like d3d11.lib that are provided in the DirectX SDK to the *.a GCC library format? I've tried the common reimp method for converting *.lib files to *.a files, but it doesn't seem to work.

Step one involves creating a definitions file:

```
bin\reimp -d d3d11.lib
```

Let's say I want to use the D3D11CreateDevice function that should be provided in this library. If I open the created definitions file everything seems to be OK:

```
LIBRARY "d3d11.dll"
EXPORTS
(...)
D3D11CreateDevice
D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain
(...)
```

Next I try to create the *.a file using the definitions file and the original lib file:

```
bin\dlltool -v -d d3d11.def -l libd3d11.a
```

This does in fact produce a valid library (and no error messages when dlltool is set to verbose), but if I try to use the function D3D11CreateDevice that should be implemented in it, I get an error:

```
undefined reference to `D3D11CreateDevice'
```

If I ask nm what symbol are present in the library (and filter using grep), I get this:

```
D:\Tools\LIB2A>bin\nm libd3d11.a | grep D3D11CreateDevice
File STDIN:
00000000 I __imp__D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain
00000000 T _D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain
00000000 I __imp__D3D11CreateDevice
00000000 T _D3D11CreateDevice
```

The imp function is the function that calls the actual implementation of D3D11CreateDevice inside the DLL. However, that actual implementation is now prefixed by an underscore.

Why is "_D3D11CreateDevice" defined while "D3D11CreateDevice" is not even though it is mentioned in the definitions file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An outdated version of dlltool will prepend an underscore to every function when converting d3d11lib. Solved it by using a dlltool.exe from MinGW-w64 4.9.2. This dlltool produces a library with the correct function names.

When using the regular d3d11.lib provided by Microsoft in combination with headers provided by anyone, a SIGSEGV will occur when stepping into the library at runtime. This means that you do have to convert to the *.a format for some reason not investigated.

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

`copy d3d11.lib libd3d11.a`

Alternatively you use `X:\path\to\d3d11.lib` on the GCC command line instead of `-ld3d11`. The GNU utilities on Windows use the same PECOFF archive format that Microsoft's tools use.

Comment: Knowing this would have saved me like a whole day of work. Thank you!

Comment: So I tried to use the the .lib file directly. Compiling and linking goes fine, but once I step into the library I get a segmentation fault. It seems that the *lib file is not compatible after all.

Comment: The library is compatible or it wouldn't have linked. I've used the DirectX SDK library as is without problems. Your problem lies elsewhere. Are you using the DirectX SDK headers? I don't think the Direct3D 11 headers are compatible with GCC, so whatever you're using instead (or whatever you've done to try make them compatible) might not have declared the functions you're using correctly.

Comment: I am currently using the MinGW-w64 D3D11 headers in combination with the libraries from the June 2010 DirectX SDK.

Comment: Why not just use the MinGW-w64 libraries?

Comment: MinGW currently only offers D3DX libraries for DX11. I need the base D3D libraries. I just came across this though: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/discussion/723797/thread/b24d5080/

Comment: Solved it. This is apparently a bug in some old version of dlltool I was using. When I tried to use the latest dlltool, all was fine.